# Linux Elementary OS Constantly WiFi Dropping

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, router, elementaryos

Two days ago, I installed Elementary OS on my ASUS K550L. Everything looks just perfect, but since first hour of exploring the system, my WiFi connection keeps dropping every several minutes.

I checked and restarted my router, but no solution.
After searching the internet for solution, I got [THIS](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/01/fix-wireless-or-wired-network-not.html), but there is a part with editing text file:

```
gksu gedit /etc/pm/config.d/unload_modules
```

and there is an error message popping out when I try to save the file, saying that the file does not exist.

I'm really loving this distro, but as I'm new to Linux, I can't seem to find a good solution for this problem.

Also, in some posts I saw people update their question with

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

so, mine is here:

```
    *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.1
       logical name: enp2s0f1
       version: 12
       serial: 10:c3:7b:27:bb:b5
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list 
     ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8411-2_0.0.1 07/08/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:42 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7914000-f7914fff memory:f7910000-f7913fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
       vendor: Ralink corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0f0
       version: 00
       serial: 54:35:30:b1:7c:2d
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=4.4.0-62-generic firmware=0.37 ip=192.168.0.101 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:19 memory:f7810000-f781ffff
```

**This happends only when I connect to my router, and the internet is fine when connecting on my mobile hotspot**

Any solutions? Thank you for your time, hope somebody can help!

Comment: The link you gave is for the symptom "network not working after resume from suspend". But from your description "every few minutes", you don't suspend your system - or do you?

Comment: The standard approach to debug problem is to look into `/var/log/syslog` or `/var/log/messages` for suspicious messages that could be related to your problem. (Use the command `less` as root in terminal window, with `sudo` if necessary). Any such messages with a timestamp close to when you loose connection? Also, you can get an idea how good your receptions is by doing `iw wlp3s0f0 station dump` in a terminal window as root (use `sudo` if necessary).

Comment: Yes, I know, that is because I tried everything else and could not find the solution. Never mind, I manged to make it work, I will post the link in the answer of my own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched a little more, and found out this solution, which worked perfectly!

Since I had a Realtek wireless card 3290, I found the solution here: [LINK](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253632/how-do-i-get-a-ralink-rt3290-wireless-card-working)

The first one example,

> NOT OFFICIAL DRIVERS FOR Kernel 4.X

This solved my problems! Hope this post will help others too.